# Prevent extrenalhit caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

If I understood correctly Facebook externalhit scrapes page every 24h for new data. Since my users are going to share dynamic images on Facebook,the image should not be cached, because it would change much more then once every 24h.

Does externalhit ignores something like:

```
 context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Is there some way to force it not to cache image? I know using linter clears cache but it would be silly to instruct my users to run linter every time they want to see a changed image instead of cached one.

I assume some script to lint urls programmatically would be agianst their TOS?

Comment: External hit ignores cache directives; it only scrapes the content; Why not create a new page for every new image, so that the URL is unique per image?

Comment: I could do that but here is the thing: 1.Users Shares a Link on Fb
2.Image changes
3.Image is now on new url?
4.User has to share new Url to Facebook?
That would be just silly to make users share new link each time image changes

Comment: So you mean, the image that has been shared, changes? I think in that case, the best solution would be to hit it with url linter before it is shared.

Comment: Yup. So users share image and it's get posted on users wall, after 1-2h image gets changed, now when someone goes to this users wall they should see new image there. I really never worked with FB api but I understand there is something like $facebook->api_client->fbml_refreshImgSrc("imageURL")? would that work? Is there a penalty for using it too much?

Comment: Sorry, but that is not possible; you cannot change the content on the wall/timeline etc after is appears there. Only new posts (shares) can have the feed content changed (if you hit url linter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different URL for each image, and have the like button point to that URL - that's basically the only way to do this - otherwise you'd retroactively be changing the details of the thing which was liked - and the fields are locked after X likes and won't be updated ( I think X = 100)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible! Just to accept answer.